# replace caption of figure

Tags: floats

I have the following:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{Figures/1a.png}
    \caption{Caption with a lot of text.......................}
  \label{Proba}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}

  \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{Figures/1b.png}
  \caption{Another caption with even more text.....................}     
  \label{Proba difference}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

which results in the following graph:
[image]

However, the captions are quite ugly next to each other. How do I move the left caption a bit to the left or right caption bit to the right?

Comment: Replace the `%` between the two minipage by say `\hfill`. Additionally, you really should not be using the `H` placement

Comment: The `floatrow` package would help greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the `%` between the two minipages by `\hspace{5mm}`

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the `floatrow`  package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{floatrow}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{floatrow}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{AliceSteadman}}
       { \caption{Ralph Steadman’s cover for \textit{Alice in Wonderland}}
      \label{Stead}}
    \qquad
     \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Busy_Bodies}}
     {\caption{Stan Laurel \& Oliver Hardy in \textit{Busy Bodies}}
      \label{Stanllie}}
    \end{floatrow}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]